# Angular material - table skeleton placeholder

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material2

I'm trying to use skeleton placeholder everywhere in my Angular 6 + Material project. I got stuck with `<table>`, since I don't know how to use placeholder when data isn't loaded yet (example image below):

[image]

What I'm using

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let v">{{ v.date }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let v">{{ v.description }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-right">Amount</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="text-right">{{ v.amount }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

My skeleton placeholder could be

```
<tr *ngFor="let s of [1, 2, 3]">
  <td><span class="sk skw-2 skh-3"></span></td>
  <td><span class="sk skw-3 skh-3"></span></td>
  <td><span class="sk skw-2 skh-3"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Which should be inserted if dataSource is empty. Any ideas how to do that?

One (***VERY UGLY***) solution is something like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource || [{}, {}, {}]">
```

And column

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="date">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let v">
    <ng-container *ngIf="v.date">
      {{ v.date }}
    </ng-container>
    <span *ngIf="!v.date" class="sk skw-2 skh-3"></span>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: you can try using *ngIf else to check if the data is there or not

Answer (score 1):

Add 2 `div` inside

`<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">`

Have one with the data and only show that when the value is not `null`

`<div *ngIf="element.position">{{element.position}}</div>`

Have the second with the placeholder only show that the value is `null`

```
<div *ngIf="!element.position" style="background-color: #e8e8e8;padding: 10px;"></div>
```

It should look something like

[image]

**OR**

If you only want one `div` use `ngClass` and apply the `css` for the placeholder to the `td` when the value is `null`

If you don't have the data, then you can just insert empty rows into your datasource object and that will build the table.  Or you can just show a loading icon, [Table retrieving data through HTTP](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Comment: Your first solution won't work. Before data is loaded there won't be anything there

Comment: As I said, if you don't have the data, you will have to add some empty rows somehow.  `let v = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      v.push({
        "position": null,
        "name": null,
        "weight": null,
        "symbol": null
      })
    }

    this.dataSource = v;`